# With block in Plug server throws MatchError instead of using else block

Tags: elixir, plug

Previously, I would use `with` blocks in Elixir Plug servers to parse parameters from requests and return a sane response if that failed. However, that doesn't seem to be working anymore (Elixir 1.11). Can anyone point out what's going on?

Here is a minimalist `Plug` server that will show the problem

```
defmodule MatchTest.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)

  get "/" do
    other_with =
      with {:ok, _} <- Map.fetch(%{}, "test") do
        :ok
      else
        :error -> :error
      end

    with conn <- Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params(conn),
         {:ok, a} = Map.fetch(conn.query_params, "a") do
      Plug.Conn.send_resp(conn, 200, "a = #{a}; other_with = #{other_with}")
    else
      :error -> Plug.Conn.send_resp(conn, 400, "Incorrect Parameters")
    end
  end

  match _ do
    Plug.Conn.send_resp(conn, 404, "Not Found")
  end
end

defmodule MatchTest do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    Supervisor.start_link(
      [{Plug.Cowboy, scheme: :http, plug: MatchTest.Router, options: [port: 4000]}],
      strategy: :one_for_one,
      name: RateLimitedServer.Supervisor
    )
  end
end
```

As expected, when I include the `a` parameter in a GET request everything works:

```
ddrexler@Drexbook-Pro:temp|$ http -v get localhost:4000/ a=="test"
GET /?a=test HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4000
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
content-length: 28
date: Mon, 15 Feb 2021 22:40:14 GMT
server: Cowboy

a = test; other_with = error
```

In particular, the first `with` clause works as expected and, when we try to `Map.fetch()` from an empty map, it jumps over into the `else` clause (You can see this because the string "other_with = error").

However, when I try to exclude the parameter I get a 500:

```
ddrexler@Drexbook-Pro:~|$ http -v get localhost:4000/
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4000
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0



HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
content-length: 0
```

And the server gets an uncaught MatchError:

```
ddrexler@Drexbook-Pro:match_test|$ mix run --no-halt
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: "else" clauses will never match because all patterns in "with" will always match
  lib/match_test.ex:15


14:40:16.341 [error] #PID<0.350.0> running MatchTest.Router (connection #PID<0.349.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: :error
        (match_test 0.1.0) lib/match_test.ex:16: anonymous fn/2 in MatchTest.Router.do_match/4
        (match_test 0.1.0) lib/plug/router.ex:284: MatchTest.Router.dispatch/2
        (match_test 0.1.0) lib/match_test.ex:1: MatchTest.Router.plug_builder_call/2
        (plug_cowboy 2.4.1) lib/plug/cowboy/handler.ex:12: Plug.Cowboy.Handler.init/2
        (cowboy 2.8.0) /Users/ddrexler/src/elixir/match_test/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:37: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
        (cowboy 2.8.0) /Users/ddrexler/src/elixir/match_test/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:300: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
        (cowboy 2.8.0) /Users/ddrexler/src/elixir/match_test/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:291: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
        (stdlib 3.13.2) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Also note the warning `"else" clauses will never match because all patterns in "with" will always match` - is clearly untrue! There's a situation where they don't match because I get a MatchError. The `else` block includes an `:error` option, which should catch this result!

Comment: You probably meant `{:ok, a} <- Map.fetch(...)` with `<-` instead of `=`

Comment: I did! How embarrassing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably already worked it out from @sbacarob's comment.

Your error is coming because when there's no `a` param: `{:ok, a} = Map.fetch(conn.query_params, "a")` is evaluated as `{:ok, a} = :error` and that raises the `MatchError`.

To avoid the `MatchError` you need to use the special `with`-specific operator `<-`.  You can think of it kind of like a "soft match" operator (where `=` is a "hard match").  The soft match lets the match fail (in a `with`) and fall through to the else/end, whereas the hard match will raise `MatchError`.

Comment: Absolutely correct. No idea how I missed not using the <- in trying to make a minimum case. Thanks!